# Is crypt32.dll included with Vista/Windows 7?

Tags: windows, dll, cryptography

Is Crypt32.dll included with Windows Vista and/or Windows 7? An official microsoft link confirming whether it is/isn't would be good. I've found the link below, but it seems to imply that Server 2003 was the last version with Crypt32 included:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379884(VS.85).aspx

If not, is there another way to access Crypt32 functionality (e.g. CertCreateSelfSignCertificate)?

UPDATE: turns out the reason that link doesn't list Vista etc as there's a new Crypto API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376210(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 includes Crypt32.dll - so does Windows Server 2008. I don't have Vista started right now, but given that W7 + Windows Server 2008 have crypt32.dll (Version 6.1.7601.17514) suggests that Vista also has it.

Edit: Crypt32.dll is also included in Vista (checked on Vista SP2, x64, version was 6.0.6002.18005).

Comment: As a matter of fact Windows 2003 Server has it, too (just checked). I don't recall the time when it was not there, to be honest. Anything in between should then have it, too.

Comment: Vista has it too. Just checked. Also edited your answer to include that info.

Comment: cheers guys, turns out the problem I was having is unrelated. Looks like that help page doesn't list crypt32 because there's a new API for crypto in Vista. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376210(v=VS.85).aspx